# Firebase Messaging gives gradle build error immediately

Tags: flutter

Trying to get up and running with a simple flutter app using the `firebase_messaging` package. Following the steps as per [the instructions](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) I changed the following files:

- pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter # This is 1.7.8+hotfix.4

  firebase_messaging: ^5.1.5
```

- android/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
   classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
}
```

- android/app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' # to the very bottom
```

Add the `google-services.json` to `android/app/google-services.json` and that's it.

Run using `flutter run` and the following error is returned:

```
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "C:\...\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\...\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> ASCII

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
  Command: C:\...\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
```

The instructions are pretty vague so perhaps I've missed something but I would've thought that should work. This is on Windows 10, I have a feeling it might be platform related.

Comment: I would recommend two things for understanding the issue. 1)  use `flutter run --verbose` for detailed error info 2) Run Android project directly using Android studio by loading `\android` folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgraded to `5.1.6` and Flutter `1.9.1+2`.

In addition to the online instructions I had to make some additional changes to get it to compile:

android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.41'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
    }
}
```

android/app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper-properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```